# How to write Spring Batch Test cases using Mockito?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm looking to write the test cases for my `Spring Batch Job` and for that I was goining through the link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/testing.html#creatingUnitTestClass and I developed below Test case and I realized that its actually working like real batch job call and that could be pathetic.

I want to simply make all the batch jobs mocked. Is there any OOTB API or I can simply make it simply using Mockito ?

```
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class Job {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        // set some env variables to allow Spring Context to load up !
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();    
        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());

        StepExecution stepExecution = jobExecution.getStepExecutions().iterator().next();

        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, stepExecution.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to simply make all the batch jobs mocked"? Which behaviour do you want to mock? The Job interface' main method is `Job.execute(JobExecution)`. What do you want to mock here? There is nothing specific to Spring Batch to do that, you can use regular Mockito APIs.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - I dont want to actually trigger the Batch Job through Test Cases which fetches details from source system and write it to target. I want to use Mockito.

Comment: In this case, you need to mock the reader and the writer. And same here, nothing specific to Spring Batch, you can mock the reader/writer as any other java code with Mockito APIs, something like: `Mockito.when(reader.read()).thenReturn(mockItem)`.

Comment: @JeffCook did you able to find the process which doesn't call actual reader & writer? I have similar use case where i dont want to DB calls (reader & writer calls). I want to mock the reader & writer data. Let me know how did you do this